# Jenkins : Dashboard view containing job names and last 5 builds in tabular format

Tags: jenkins

I have multiple jobs on Jenkins, now I want a dashboard view in a tabular form showing each job with their last 5 build(or more). Basically the table contains all the jobs one below another in y axis and their respective build numbers with status on x axis.
Please provide the plugin name which can be configured to get this view.

Answer (score 0):

You have many plugins for this, for example:

- [Build Monitor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin)
- [Dashboard View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View)